# nginx robots.txt for two different domains and nginx.conf - but robots.txt in one folder

Tags: nginx, robots.txt, shopware

I use Shopware and have two different webshops with two domains, domainA and domainB.  Now, they have only one robots.txt file in the public folder for both domains.

I need to go online with domainA, but can't do this because domainB should not be found in Google, etc. I have domainA.conf and domainB.conf, how can I use two different robots.txt files? Each for one domain?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help to know what actions or code you've tried.

Comment: Maybe the answers to this, question will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308779/nginx-different-robots-txt-for-alternate-domainhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308779/nginx-different-robots-txt-for-alternate-domain since it isn't really shopware depended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx: different robots.txt for alternate domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308779/nginx-different-robots-txt-for-alternate-domain)

Answer (score 0):

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/html/shopware/public/robots/robots.txt;
}
```

Comment: Hi JohannesH, please edit your answer to add a short description what it accomplishes.